# How to send several files (images) using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? Site made in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

On my Laravel website, I am trying to send a form with several images in a proxy system, where I receive the data through the request and then format this data to send through `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

I have the following error:
`local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Array to string conversion' in /code/lib/Core/ProxyToCore15.php:53`

The structure of data sent is this:

```
array(2) {
  ["json"]=>
  string(254) "{"contact":{"name":"teste","phone":"(00) 00000-0000","type":"3"},"attributes":{"name":"teste","phone":"(00) 00000-0000","address":"a","authorization":"Autorizado intermediação de venda e ou locação","type":"3","url":"localhost/cadastre-seu-imovel?"}}"
  ["files"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(CURLFile)#268 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpLDEAca"
      ["mime"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["postname"]=>
      string(14) "HERO_Model.jpg"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(CURLFile)#254 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpMkBpGp"
      ["mime"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["postname"]=>
      string(23) "20220929104711_2202.jpg"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(CURLFile)#253 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpmAlpEh"
      ["mime"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["postname"]=>
      string(19) "carrosnagaragem.jpg"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(CURLFile)#269 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpAnelKL"
      ["mime"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["postname"]=>
      string(54) "original-d545b109b5f7829cd6005cd8beca05ef-1024x659.jpg"
    }
    
  }
}
```

Sending just one image is working:

```
array(2) {
  ["json"]=>
  string(254) "{"contact":{"name":"teste","phone":"(00) 00000-0000","type":"3"},"attributes":{"name":"teste","phone":"(00) 00000-0000","address":"a","authorization":"Autorizado intermediação de venda e ou locação","type":"3","url":"localhost/cadastre-seu-imovel?"}}"
  ["files"]=>
  object(CURLFile)#264 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpjfDijd"
    ["mime"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["postname"]=>
    string(14) "HERO_Model.jpg"
  }
}
```

From what I observed, the error occurs because the files key is an array when I send several images. I tried to use `http_build_query` on the files array, I get another error, 504 getaway time out.

My current code is like this:

```
public function send()
    {

        $curl = curl_init();
        $url  = config('services.core15.url') .'/'.$this->request->path().'?'.$this->request->getQueryString();
        //dd($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $headers  = $this->getHeaders();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $this->request->getMethod());

        if ($this->request->method() === "POST") {
            $headers[] = 'content-type: multipart/form-data';
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->getBody());
            //dd($this->getBody());
            //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['{["json"]="contact":"1"}']);
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        try {
            $response       = curl_exec($curl);
            $headerSize     = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

            //$responseHeader = explode("\n", substr($response, 0, $headerSize));
            //dd($responseHeader);

            $responseBody   = substr($response, $headerSize);
            $responseCode   = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

            $result =  $this->makeResponse($responseBody, substr($response, 0, $headerSize), $responseCode);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e, curl_error($curl));
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        return $result;
    };


     public function getBody()
    {
        $data = $this->request->all();
        $postFields = []; // Inicialize postFields como um array vazio
    
        foreach ($this->request->files->keys() as $fileKey) {
            $files = $this->request->file($fileKey);
            $toUpload = null;
    
            if (count($files) > 1) {
                /** @var UploadedFile[] $files */
                foreach ($files as $index => $file) {
                    $toUpload["file" . ($index + 1)] = curl_file_create($file->getPathname(), $file->getMimeType(), $file->getClientOriginalName());
                }
            } else { 
                $toUpload = curl_file_create($data['files'][0]->getPathname(), $data['files'][0]->getClientMimeType(), $data['files'][0]->getClientOriginalName());
            }
    
            // Defina os campos de postFields dentro do loop
            $postFields = [
                'json' => $data['json'],
                'files' => $toUpload   
            ];
        }
    
        $data = $postFields;
    
        return $data;
    }

I tried to use http_build_query on the files array, but I get another error, 504 getaway time out.
```